# Strange baking result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I got this baking texture out of this mesh, it as a normal albedo map and emissive, I just simply need to bake the material with the direct and indirect lightning from the emissive, but as it looks, the baking does not work. [image: UV Result] the texture does not translate to reality, do you guys know what is going on? The last image is how it looks in unity. I need help thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem, actually you cannot bake a 1 mesh with 2 types of materials, a ColorBase and Emissive cannot be baked, doing a recap a mesh cannot iluminate itself. Maybe it sounds logical, but i tried so many times and results of trying has shown me that it is no posible.